# Get percentage values for tool tip

Tags: lightweight-charts

I am creating a tool tip but I have set my series to percentage.

```
newSeries.priceScale().applyOptions({mode: PriceScaleMode.Percentage});
```

No I want to grap the calculated percentage value to use it in my tool-tip.

But this always gives me the original price, not the converted percentage value:

```
console.log(
  originSeries
    .priceFormatter()
    .format(param.seriesData.entries().next().value[1].value),
);
```